# How to replace a React Components with another React Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, chakra-ui

I got something like this

```js
<Box>
   <SomethingA>
</Box
```

I want to replace `Box.SomethingA` to `Box.SomethingB`

```js
<Box>
   <SomethingB>
</Box>
```

#### How I can do it?

Comment: Import SomethingB and just replace it in your return.

Comment: @Konstantin but like what?

Comment: Do you want to do this on a certain condition?

Comment: @AnkitGarg well the `<SomethingA>` is a **world map** in `<svg>` format. And in that `<svg>` has a `<path> = Country`. So for example when user click on a `<path>` that has name `USA` then the `<SomethingA>` will change to `<SomethingB` which is equal to another `<svg>` that has **USA map**

Comment: Try the below link. This will help you in achieving the scenario you mentioned. https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: @AnkitGarg no sir. I am using a `useEffect()` that has `EventListener` inside it. So when I `retunr()` something then others **React componens** will be removed. I want to something like `document.getElementsId("SomethingA")` and then `return(<SomethingB>)`, but doesn't work!

Comment: It will be great if you can share your code on stackblitz or any other platform. But I think conditional should work. Only we need to see if it has been used correctly or not.

Comment: @AnkitGarg https://pastebin.com/XJ9wAUJP, maybe that would make you figure things out better?

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you want to replace it after an event has occurred, for ex: `button click`.
You can try this:

```
function App(){
  const [box, changeBox] = useState(true)

  return(
    <div>
      <button onClick={()=>{changeBox(!box)}} >Click</button>
      <Box>
        { box ? <SomethingA/> : <SomethingB/>}
      </Box>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: well, I want to `<SomethingA/>` to render first and then with some condition to replace `<SomethingA/>` with `<SomethingB/>`. But thanks you

Comment: yeah, I figured, but you have not mentioned your `condition` that will trigger the replacement, however, this is basically you achieve that. If you find my answer helpful please vote it.